# How to tell which FloatSpin is firing the EVT_FLOATSPIN event in wxPython?

Tags: event-handling, wxpython

I want to capture the FLOATSPIN events triggered by my floatspinners but I need to know which FloatSpin control has fired this event. This is required so that I can update the values of a dictionary.

The FloatSpin controls have been created based upon a dictionary of key:value pairs. The key being the uniqueid of my FloatSpin control, and the value being the default value of the control. I want to update my dictionary k:v pairs, and the value that I am updating will come from the FloatSpin control event.

Given the following (stripped down) example, how would I capture the unique id of the control firing the event?

```python
firstFS = FS.FloatSpin(self, -1, min_val=0, max_val=None, increment=1, value=1, agwStyle=FS.FS_RIGHT)
secondFS = FS.FloatSpin(self, -1, min_val=0, max_val=None, increment=1, value=1, agwStyle=FS.FS_RIGHT)

self.Bind(FS.EVT_FLOATSPIN, self.OnFloatSpin)

def OnFloatSpin(self, event):
    floatspin = event.GetEventObject()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent a few hours trying to figure out but I got it!

```python
firstFS = FS.FloatSpin(self, -1, min_val=0, max_val=None, increment=1, value=1, agwStyle=FS.FS_RIGHT)
firstFS.SetName('firstFS')  # for example
secondFS = FS.FloatSpin(self, -1, min_val=0, max_val=None, increment=1, value=1, agwStyle=FS.FS_RIGHT)
secondFS.SetName('secondFS')  # for example

self.Bind(FS.EVT_FLOATSPIN, self.OnFloatSpin)

def OnFloatSpin(self, event):
    floatspin = event.GetEventObject()
    floatspinID = event.GetId()  # grab the widgets id that is firing the event
    '''OR'''
    floatspinName = event.GetEventObject().GetName()  # grab the widget name
```

Comment: if you give them unique "name" parameters, then you could also use your floatspin object to do floatspin.GetName() too

Comment: I was just about to add this, as this has proven more useful!! Thanks Mike, I stumbled upon http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/09/20/wxpython-binding-multiple-widgets-to-the-same-handler/ after I came here to post the question. Everyone should take a look at that link!

Comment: If I'd found your question sooner, I would have linked to that article in my own solution.